# How to redirect from <li> items that are a result of a search component to another page using Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm a beginner to Vuejs and Web development.I have created a search component that loads data from a database.The data is drug names that are in the Database. ([The search results look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o41PK.png)).I now need to redirect the user to a page showing drug data.
This is the code where i display the list items.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="search">
      <BaseSearch v-model="query" v-on:change="search" />
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="(drug,index) in getDrugs" v-bind:key="index">{{drug}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I now need to redirect the user to a page containing drug information based on the list element clicked.Can someone help me with some suggestions?

Comment: You need to redirect  by v-on:change="search" or when you click on li elemnent?

Comment: I need to redirect if the user clicks on a particular list item,(a drug name). This should take the user to a page with drug information.I'm sorry I hadn't made it clear in the question.I have edited the question to make it clearer now.

Comment: Ok I've answered it as you need please see it.